# Accept types compatible with Path to produce a PathBuf?

Tags: rust

I want to hold a `PathBuf` inside my structure:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

struct Foo {
    p: PathBuf,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(p: PathBuf) -> Foo {
        Foo { p }
    }
}
```

Something like this works fine for `Foo::new(Path::new("a").join("b"))`, but I also want to support `Foo::new(Path::new("a"))`:

```
fn main() {
    Foo::new(Path::new("a").join("b"));
    // Foo::new(Path::new("a"));
}
```

How should I do it? Is it possible to implement with one method, or should I use two methods? I know about `P: AsRef<Path>`, but looks like it requires additional copy in the case of

```
let p: PathBuf = Path::new("a").join("b");
let foo = Foo::new(p);
```

so it is not suitable for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a generic type that can be converted [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) a `PathBuf`:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

struct Foo {
    p: PathBuf,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new<P>(p: P) -> Foo
    where
        P: Into<PathBuf>,
    {
        Foo { p: p.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo::new(Path::new("a").join("b"));
    Foo::new(Path::new("a"));
    Foo::new("a");
}
```